# Angular ngsw-config.json glob pattern problem

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

I want to exclude some js file/s from being cached by a service worker. Lets say that i want to include all js files except ones that starts with some string for example: `config`.

```
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css"
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Things that i have tried:

1. `"/^(?!config).*.js"` and similar combinations
2. Prefixing `config.js` file with `_`, so `_config.js` and then having a pattern that exclude all the files starting with `_` in a way: `/[^_].*.js` or similar combinations

And nothing worked. Usually output is that all the files are included or none of the files are included (probably not a valid format). I see at the specification that angular in this case using some kind of "limited glob format" but i was not able to make this working. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVED:

```
  "/*.js",
  "!/config.js"
```

Include all the js files and then exclude particular file/pattern suing `!` in the beginning (and not somewhere in the middle)